# Multi-threading for multi-core processors

Tags: android, multithreading, multicore

I have Samsung Galaxy S3, which used its own Exynos 4 Quad processor.
So I  want to optimize my app, that it can use all 4 cores of processor.

So I made some tests:

1. Run task in one thread. Processing time - 8 seconds.
2. Run task in four threads. Processing time - still 8 sec.

   ```
    new Thread() {
       public void run() {
                       // do 1/4 of task
       }
   }.start();

   new Thread() {
       public void run() {
                       // do 1/4 of task
       }
   }.start();

   new Thread() {
       public void run() {
                       // do 1/4 of task
       }
   }.start();

   new Thread() {
       public void run() {
                       // do 1/4 of task
       }
   }.start();
   ```
3. Run task in ExecutorService. And processing time - still 8 sec.

   ```
   ExecutorService threadPool = null;
   threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

   threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            // do 1/4 of task
                         }});
   threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            // do 1/4 of task
                         }});
   threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            // do 1/4 of task
                         }});
   threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            // do 1/4 of task
                         }});
   ```

Looks like all work done synchronously. Why its not paralleling ?

Comment: Without a real project, instead of incomplete samples like this, it is impossible to tell you. Perhaps all four are competing on some resource, like doing disk I/O, that makes CPU parallelism less effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try my tests, in C or Java:

http://bigflake.com/cpu-spinner.c.txt
  http://bigflake.com/MultiCore.java.txt

When MultiCore.java is run on a Nexus 4, I see:

```
Thread 1 finished in 1516ms (1267234688)
Thread 3 finished in 1494ms (1519485328)
Thread 0 finished in 1530ms (51099776)
Thread 2 finished in 1543ms (-1106614992)
All threads finished in 1550ms
```

**Update:**
It's useful to watch the test with systrace.  As part of answering a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842864/multiprocessing-on-android/17959192#17959192) I set up a page that [shows the systrace output](http://bigflake.com/systrace/) for this test.  You can see how the threads are scheduled, and watch the other two cores spin up.